# Uploading NuGet add-on package to Episerver throws exception

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, episerver

I am researching on EPiserver. I set up the environment localhost, I create an addOn and now I am trying to uploaded as I have already created a .nupkg file. But I receive this exception:

"The schema version of 'TestAddOn' is incompatible with version 2.0.30619.9119 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.
"
I run

```
 nuget.exe update -Self
```

on my pc but I have already the latest version.

```
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 4.6.2.
NuGet.exe is up to date.
```

What can it be the mismatch here? Thank you in advance.

*UPDATE*

Here is the nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
<metadata>
<id>$id$</id>
<version>$version$</version>
<title>$title$</title>
<authors>$author$</authors>
<owners>$author$</owners>
<licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
<projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
<iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
<requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
<description>$description$</description>
<releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
<copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
<tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
```

Comment: Sounds like your `.nuspec` file might be invalid?

Comment: How can I validate it Ted?

Comment: Perhaps complement your question with the contents of your `.nuspec` file.

Comment: Thank you Ted, I added it as an update on the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe strange a lot but it needed to update NuGet.Core package to a newer version. For instance from 2.0.3 to 2.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

> Uploading NuGet add-on package to Episerver throws exception

According to the error messages, it seems your nuget package using a feature that is not supported by the old version of NuGet your are using. You should update the NuGet extension for Visual Studio or `nuget.exe` in `.nuget` folder:

1. **Update NuGet extension for Visual Studio**:

   Go to Tools > Extensions and Updates... > Select the Updates tab, Look for NuGet Package Manager and click the Update button. If there is no update button, you may need to use a later version of VS, for example, Visual Studio 2013,2015....
2. **Update `nuget.exe` in `.nuget` folder**：

   If you have `.neget` folder in your project, which with nuget.exe in it, you need open a CMD and switch the path to the `.nuget` folder, then use the command `nuget.exe update -Self`. If you do not include any `nuget.exe` in your solution, ignore this suggestion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leo Liu! I had already ran this two cases. At the first one, NuGet Package Manager is full updated. I am using VS 2015. I don't know if I need to go to 2017 version. And at the second one, I don't include any nuget.exe in my solution.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, have you tried to upload any other nuget package  to Episerver, like, `Newtonsoft.Json`? If it successful, this issue should be related to your nuget package. If it still have this issue, it should be related to the Episerver environment set.

Comment: That's something clever. I used latest version (11.0.2) of Newtonsoft.Json and still getting the same error.

Comment: So this issue should not related to your nuget package itself. Could you make sure the version you are using is 4.6.2 not 2.0.30619.9119? When you upload the package, have you switch path to the location of nuget.exe 4.6.2?

Comment: Again, there should be a old nuget.exe exists on your PC, **have you check if you set any old nuget.exe path into system variable**? I have met similar issue before, the member set the old nuget.exe path into the system variable, it always use the old one.

Comment: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\nuget>nuget.exe update -Self
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 4.6.2.
NuGet.exe is up to date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174629/discussion-between-leo-liu-msft-and-grlouk).